# Return Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, return

I have two classes:

```
public class Foo<T>{}

public class Bar
{
    private List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    public Foo GetFoo(int index)
    {
        return foos[index];
    }
}
```

However, both the list and method say that i need a type parameter for the Foos i specify, but i just want Foos in general, so i could add a Foo< int >, a Foo< float >, a Foo< Baz > etc. etc. to the list, and then have the method return a Foo with an unknown type. And making GetFoo generic is OK if it helps, but I can't figure out how it would.

Comment: The type `Foo` and `Foo<T>` are entirely different types, despite the similarity in name.

Comment: right, I get that, so what do i replace Foo with... Foo<T> doesn't help.

Comment: Yup, those work! Thanks!

Comment: Darn, got another problem now. That didn't solve it... now anything that inherits from Foo<T> isn't being seen as the abstract Foo. I'll edit the post. EDIT: Nevermind, I'm stupid. fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class Foo 
{ 
    //general foo logic here
}
public class Foo<T>: Foo 
{ 
    //generic type specific information here
}

public class Bar
{
    private List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    public Foo GetFoo(int index)
    {
        return foos[index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make `Foo<T>` derive from a base class (or implement an interface) that is non-generic.  You could then return a `List<IFoo>` with the properties that aren't specific to the type `T`.

This would allow you to have a single list containing any type of `Foo<T>`.